# Resume Celery job.apply_async.join()

Tags: celery

*TL;DR:*  If my producer process crashes after sending some work to the consumers, how can it resume waiting for the consumers to complete their work once it restarts?

---

`producer.py` dispatches work items to a group of consumers (registered Celery tasks), like so:

```
from celery import group, signature

job = group(
    signature(task_name, args=(x,)) for x in xrange(100)
)

group_result = job.apply_async()

group_result.join()  # blocks until tasks complete
```

The consumers take a long time to complete, so it's possible/expected that the producer will sometimes die during the call to `join()`. When the producer dies, it is restarted.

**When the produces restarts, is there a way to resume the join?**

I'm a Celery newbie; have combed through docs and examples but haven't found an answer to this. Hoping the experts can help point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, my solution was to store the task ids (in some external file/db/whatever).

```
job = group(
    signature(task_name, args=(x,)) for x in xrange(100)
)

group_result = job.apply_async()

# store group_result.results somewhere durable
persist(some_db, group_result.results)

group_result.join()  # blocks until tasks complete
```

Now, if the `join` above fails, we can recover like this:

```
# read tasks from persistent storage
previous_pending_results = read_previously_persisted_results(some_db)

for result in previous_pending_results:
    if result.status != 'SUCCESS':
        ...
```